# How to pass the value of picturebox image to another picturebox using array vb.net

Tags: arrays, database, vb.net

I'm beginner at vb.net please help me
How can i pass my picturebox1.image to picturebox2.image and the value of picturebox2.image to picturebox3.image. My point is, Everytime the new image arrive it's like the images moving forward.the incoming image will go to picturebox1. And the old value of picturebox1 will move to picturebox2 and the value of picturebox2 will go to picturebox3. I don't know how to construct the logic in coding. Help me please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Do you have any code, what have you tried, what errors, if any are you getting?  We'll need a lot more information, there are a gazillion ways to deal with picture boxes and images.

Comment: @mtr.web thanks a lot for the reminders

Comment: @PrescottChartier i've tried picturebox1.image = picturebox2.image and picturebox3.image = picturebox2.image but all of this code is not what i want. Although they're passing value. But all of my picturebox had the same output all i want is like what i'm asking for. If there's a new incoming image. Then the images will move to next image. Help me please :(

Comment: @PrescottChartier someone told me use array to do this but i don't know how to do that could you help me?

Comment: The reminders were to help you remember that you need to include the code that you have tried, as mentioned by @PrescottChartier.  It is very hard to help if you can't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Although they're passing value. But all of my picturebox had the same output` Well, think about it for a second. Once you use `Pic2.Image = Pic1.Image`, the first image becomes in both pictureboxes. Then you use `Pic3.Image = Pic2.Image`, again adding _the same picture_ to Pic3, and so on. What do you expect would happen? Have you tried doing it backwards?

Comment: Start with your last picturebox and work backwards for example 5 =4, 4=3, 3=2, 2=1, 1= New.  The last statement should be where the first picturebox loads the new image.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i think it will get the same ouput as i did. Because i'm just getting the value of picturebox.image

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf how can i do that correctly? Coz i did what you said and the value of picturebox2 and picturebox3 has equal to picturebox1. If you don't mind. Can i have some source code?

Comment: Thanks to all of you sir. I did the coding. I appreciate all of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there are a number of ways the accomplish this.  I use my database to store images all the time, so I'll show you a method for displaying the images in the order they are retrieved from the database.  You are correct in that if you assign  pic2.image to pic1.image and so on, the picture boxes will all have the same image because that's the value of pic1, reversing the order does the same thing.  You need to assign the image you want in each picture box to that picture box.

First I create a list of images, they're all jpg's but it shouldn't matter:

```
Imports System.Drawing ' <---- I assume you have this at the top of the code behind
Dim MyImages as List(of Image)
```

I retrieve the images from the database in a datatable in order of the primary key ascending, key is 1 to n and fill the list:

```
Dim x as Integer = 1
pictureboxname = "pic" & x
For Each MyDataRow as DataRow in MyTable.Rows
    ' Load the list, the image is in column zero
    MyImages.Add(MyDataRow(0))
    ' because this is the initial list, you can also populate the pictureboxes too
    ' you need to use the picturebox name in an expression to populate the pictureboxes in a loop.
    ' Something like this .... this is untested
    (pictureboxname).Image = MyImages(MyImages.Count -1) 
    ' and change picturebox name to the next picture box
    x += 1
    ' I assume picturebox name is pic1, pic2, etc ....
    pictureboxname = "pic" + x
    ' you'll have to limit this loop to the number of pictureboxes you have if they are less than the number of images, but you get the idea
Next
```

When a new images is added, you can then add it to the list and database at the same time and then repopulate the picture boxes.

```
StoreImage(NewImage)
MyImages.Add(NewImage)

Dim x as integer = 1
pictureboxname = "pic" & x
For each MyImage as Image in MyImages
    ' assign each image in turn to the picture boxes ... again, untested
    (pictureboxname).Image = MyImage
    x += 1
    pictureboxname = "pic" & x
    ' again, you'll have to limit this loop to the number of pictureboxes you have if it is less than the number of images ....
Next
```

This is not be exactly what you're looking for, but should get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. This is very helpful. again Thank you very much sir